# Redirecionamento em Ajax

Tags: javascript

Como eu posso realizar um redirecionamento para um página qualquer após a função ser realizada com sucesso? Script abaixo:
Sou um pouco leigo com JavaScript. Obrigado!

```js
function alterarquantidade(id,tipo) {
  var quantidadeInput = document.getElementById("quantidade_produto"+id).value;
  $.ajax({
      url: 'alterarquantidade.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {id_produto: id, quantidade : quantidadeInput, tipo : tipo},
      success: function (retorno) {
          console.log(retorno);
      }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer um redirect de página redefinindo a propriedade href do objeto [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href):

`document.location.href`

Então, no seu caso, supondo que por exemplo queira redirecionar para `https://pagina-de-redirecionamento.test`, poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
function alterarquantidade(id,tipo) {
    var quantidadeInput = document.getElementById("quantidade_produto"+id).value;
    $.ajax({
            url: 'alterarquantidade.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id_produto: id, quantidade : quantidadeInput, tipo : tipo},
            success: function (retorno) {
               document.location.href = "https://pagina-de-redirecionamento.test";

            }
        });
    }
```

Ressalto que a solução acima não é específcia ou relacionada a contextos de chamadas XHR (ajax) e poderia ser usada em outros cenários.

Comment: Bom dia! tentei mas não funcionou.

Comment: Tem certeza que está caindo na função de callback success do $.ajax?

Comment: Sim, ele esta fechando no callback success